# Syntax Error : what I am missing from Python "for" loop with a range

Tags: python

I get the idea of what I am supposed to do, but I believe I am missing a step here somehwere... I get a syntax error before from line 1!

```
range(1, 51)

For answer in range:
   if answer % 3 == 0 and answer % 5 ==0
    print (“Wolly Bully”)
elseif answer % 3 == 0 and answer % 5 = <0
        print (“Wolly”)
elseif answer % 3 = <0 and answer % 5 == 0
    print (“Bully”)
elseif answer % 3 = <0 and answer % 5 = <0
    print (str(answer) + " ", end = "")
```

Comment: Can you share the code as it appears in the file? Also, what is the error message?

Comment: `elseif` isn't Python syntax, and neither is `For` (the keywords are `for` and `elif`)

Comment: There are several syntactic and logical issues here. What is `range(1, 51)` supposed to do by itself? What is `For`? That's not `for`. What is `range` by itself supposed to do? What's with the angled quotes? What is `elseif` What is `answer % 3 = <0` or `answer % 5 = <0`? Where are the colons to begin blocks? I'm not trying to be cruel, but please go through a Python tutorial.

Comment: Also, `“` isn't a valid quote in Python, and neither is `”`; only `"` is.

Comment: You have no colons after your `if` statements, your indentation is all over the place, and you have weird quotes. You need to use an IDE to write code, not a text editor. There's no such thing as `elseif` in Python.

Comment: ugh.. we have been using for all semester.  ok back to google... Thanks for helping!

Comment: "ugh.. we have been using for all semester"—you have been using _what_ all semester? All of the issues listed above are definite problems.

Comment: You all are awesome... Word might be my problem.  I have changed it to for a million times!

Comment: "Word might be my problem"—yeah, that's **a** problem. But not your only one. It might be responsible for the angle quotes, but it _is **not a text editor**. Why would you use Word for programming?_ Please tell me your instructor isn't recommending that...

Comment: https://www.python.org/downloads/
Download the newest version, install it, run it, click *File*, click *New File*, and you should be all set,

Comment: @ericl16384, running Python doesn't give anything that would have a "file" menu. It's an interpreter or, given no input, a REPL. Are you talking about IDLE?

Comment: Yes, I mean run the IDLE. Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: No he isn't Im sure it is me.. I started using word to just try to do a pseudocode and panic'd from there...

Comment: Thank you all so much!  I switched to notepad (since I do school at night on my work computer and only access python through a portal...  I used a combination of your suggestions and fixed an issue on my bottom line to get the full answer that was required.  Thanks for helping me understand where I was going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You can define a range with `range(1, 51)`, but `range` is a function, so you need to do something with the range it returns.

For example:

```
my_range = range(1, 51)
for answer in my_range:
    ...
```

And because you don't need the range for anything else, this is a better solution:

```
for answer in range(1, 51):
    ...
```

There's some more issues with your code, many of them typos - here's a corrected version (not guaranteed to work correctly, but it runs):

```
for answer in range(1, 51):
    if answer % 3 == 0 and answer % 5 == 0:
        print("Wolly Bully")
    elif answer % 3 == 0 and answer % 5 < 0:
        print("Wolly")
    elif answer % 3 < 0 and answer % 5 == 0:
        print("Bully")
    elif answer % 3 < 0 and answer % 5 < 0:
        print(str(answer) + " ", end = "")
```

A couple of types of changes:

- `elif` instead of `elseif`
- a colon after an `if` or `elif`
- correct indentation
- `<=` instead of `= <`
- correct quotes
- no capitalisation on `for`
- space between a function (print) and its argument list
- mutually exclusive `if` and `elif` expressions (if something is does not meet `if x == y`, there's not point in `elif x <= y` and it's clearer to write `elif x < y`, since that's the only case for which the code will be executed.

You are probably using an unsuitable editor to write your code, given the capitalisation and strange quotes - it's highly recommended to use a programming editor or IDE, like VSCode (free), PyCharm (free Community) or many other (also free) alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

There are several errors, use `range` with `for`, it's `elif` in Python and most comparison operators need to be corrected (`<=` instead of `=>`):

```
for answer in range(1, 51):
    if answer % 3 == 0 and answer % 5 == 0:
        print("Wolly Bully")
    elif answer % 3 == 0 and answer % 5 <= 0:
        print("Wolly")
    elif answer % 3 <= 0 and answer % 5 == 0:
        print("Bully")
    elif answer % 3 <= 0 and answer % 5 <= 0:
        print(str(answer) + " ", end="")
```

Out:

```
Wolly Bully
Wolly Bully
Wolly Bully
```

Comment: I'm guessing you meant `!=` and not `<=`? Presumably the teacher only used the words `Wolly` and `Bully` instead of something else to prevent the students from googling for *that infamous interview question*.